# How to access a property file using java using Weblogic Server?

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

I have one property file .properties and I can load that file in stand alone Java Class as below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
    FileInputStream fis =
        new FileInputStream("D:\\Examples\\Simple\\src\\properties.xml");
    props.loadFromXML(fis);
    // props.list(System.out);
    path = props.getProperty("path");
    System.out.println("\nThe path property: "
        + props.getProperty("path"));
    props.load(new FileInputStream(path));
    filePath = props.getProperty("path");
    System.out.println(filePath);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I need to implement logic that can allow me load the property file using Weblogic Server. So basically anytime i change anything in .proprties file i don't need to build the applicatio everytime and it can be integrated with server. I am using Jdeveloper and Weblogic Server 10.3. How can i setup Property file with server based java files?

Comment: Why would it work differently in WebLogic? Java code is Java code.

Comment: for loading property file right now i am using Fileinput stream so if someday i change the location of that property file or may be i change contents of .properties file then use of FileInputStream is not a good way. And ofcourse Java code is java code but there will be some way to put .properties file in Weblogic server configuration so i can load the property file when integrated with Weblogic server. And i don't need to specify the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

In your web-logic startup batch file add below line

set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -DconfigFile=file-path

In your java program retrieve the file-path using

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("configFile");
```

Comment: Where this Startup Batch file will be there in Weblogic 10.3?

Comment: You will have to restart the server every time there is a property file change.

Comment: How do you start your weblogic server ?.You must be using some batch(.bat) file, right ?

Comment: yes i go here C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\SOA_Domain\startWebLogic.cmd and run this file . You mean the same as .bat file?

Comment: Edit that file and add set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -DconfigFile=file-path

Comment: I've edited the startWebLogic.cmd and added the above line now how should i read that in Java?

Comment: Yes I am referring to .bat file which you use to start the weblogic.

Comment: String filePath = System.getProperty("configFile");
as you have provided "configFile" as the key value in the batch file.

Comment: The below Code is giving me "null" and It is still a stand alone .java class.       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
       TestProperty testProp = new TestProperty();
      testProp.setMessage();
       }               try {
                  
                           String filePath = System.getProperty("configFile"); 
            System.out.println(filePath);
                }
               catch(Exception e)
               {
               e.printStackTrace();
               }

Comment: Did you restart the weblogic after making changes?..And just try to print System.getProperty("configFile"); and see what happens.

Comment: yes i did restarted the weblogic Server But Mr. Shashank my TestProperty.java is standalone class right now so It's not basically integrated with webserver. It's simple class and i can not get that configuration thing which i'hv added in WLS. So it's printing Null.

Comment: Ohhk..Can't you test that with your server based Java files?

Comment: Prepare a standalone jsp and then try to print that.

Comment: I am getting Deployment failed error .06:36:19 PM] ####  Deployment incomplete.  ####
[06:36:19 PM] Remote deployment failed
#### Cannot run application TestJms due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[Application TestJms stopped and undeployed from Server Instance IntegratedWebLogicServer]
Please find attached PropertyTest.jsp content.<body bgcolor="maroon" text="white">
<center>
<%
out.println("Message: "+System.getProperty("configFile"));
%> 
</center>
</body>

Answer (score 1):

If you go strictly by the spec, you cannot load files from within an app-server.  You need to either load it using a classloader or put your config in a database.

**Classloader**

The classloader is a utility responsible for loading bytecode from files, urls or other places into memory where the java runtime can use it to create classes.  The classloader is thus the interface between the java-vm and some kind of storage.  Classloaders hide the details of how resources are accessed, thus enables you to load resources independent of whether they are in a file or other places.  In an applications server, java would like that you don't assume having a file-system available (your classes can come from somewhere else), and load resources solely through classloaders.

But of course, somewhere in the stack, the classloader does actually access the filesystem, so the question is how to configure this connection.  This is where it becomes hairy, because in an application server there are several classloaders (atleast one for each application) and it is not safe to make any assumptions on how these are structured.  There are basically two options:
 - you typicalle have your application packaged in a war or ear-file which contains classes and jar-files.  You can put your .properties-file together with these classes and load it through the "local" classloader ("local" in quotes, because this is not a real term, and as I said, you cannot make any assumptions here).
 - since this means re-packaging your war/ear-file each time you want to change parameters, this isn't really much easier than re-building your application.  The alternative is to make your config-file available to the system-wide classloader defined on startup.  This is configured by the CLASSPATH environment variable (typically in the bat/cmd/sh-script responsible for starting weblogic, as mentioned by others).  Thus, what you do is: create a directory for configuration-files, add this to the CLASSPATH in the startup-script, load with the following code (untested):

```
// the classloader is referenced from a class, might as well use the current
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
// getSystemResourceAsStream loads a resource using the default classloader, 
// as opposed to using the classloader which "this" was loaded from
InputStream in = cl.getSystemResourceAsStream("com/me/config.properties");
```

you can load properties from this input stream the same way you did for files.

**Database**

An even more robust route would be to store all of your configuration in a database and load it through a DataStore using JDBC.  However, there isn't a default API for loading from a database into a Properties-object, so you would need to make this yourself.

A simple design would be to have a database-table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE config (
    key varchar(255) primary key,
    value varchar(255)
)
```

The code for parsing this into a properties-object is left as an exercise to the reader (I guess google can tell you if someone else has done something similar)

Comment: I am newbie to Weblogic server and serverside file reading so yes ofcourse if you can elaborate what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change the location of the file without rebuilding the application, then externalize the location, for example, by passing a system property to the weblogic server:

```
-Dmy.properties.location=D:/foo/bar.properties
```

If you want to be able to reload the content of the file at runtime, without restarting the server, then read the file each time you need to access one of its properties (slow), or use Apache commons configuration, for example, which can reload properties file when they change.